# How to use google news search on console application?

Tags: c#, google-news

I want to search my company on google news for each hour by scheduled console application (c#).
How can i use google news api or something else? I need to search in one language, and sorted by date.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts). You can enter search terms related to news (pick from drop down menu) have them emailed to you once a day or as it happens (sorry, no hourly). Click create alert. and you're done! Hope it helps-CodeKid1001